# Trying to erase images from a folder using an html button that calls php code?

Tags: php, html, image, button

I'm trying to use a button in my html code to erase images that I had created in php. I've read a lot on other solutions and have no clue why my code isn't working. 
Here I have html code with a button, that when the user selects it, I need to switch to another page of my website, but prior to that I want the images to be deleted. It should do this by running the function "deleteImages()":

```
    <form id="formGoBack" action="<?php echo $ShopPage; ?>" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="formGoBack" onClick="deleteImages()" class="btn btn-primary" >Go Back </button>
          </form>
```

I also have a function within the html section that runs the deleteImages() function which will run php code:

```
<script>
function deleteImages(){
//function to delete images if the user chooses to goback:
<?php
if (isset($_POST['formGoBack'])){
unlink($outlineimageloc); 
unlink($imageaftersmooth);
unlink($jpegorigimageloc); 
unlink($OrigImageSavename);

}
    ?>
}
</script>
```

I've tried this several different ways (even just adding all of these unlink functions to the action portion of my form). However, when I put the unlinks into the action portion, it would automatically delete the images without the button being pressed. The way it is now, with the php code in the function, the images do not get deleted at all, even when the button is pressed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The php code executes on the server, the script tag denotes javascript that runs in the browser. Maybe you could do an ajax call triggered by the form's onsubmit to trigger a delete images php script or check at the start of $ShopPage's code to see if a certain parameter has been set and delete the images then.

Comment: As now it will not delete. Because you use a function call. Remove the function biit and it will work. Or use: function deleteImages($filename){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I suppose you could already handle the file deleting part (get correct path of the files to be deleted and unlink them). So I think what you want to do is:

1) Show a form with `Go Back` button;

2) Click the button and delete the files;

3) Redirect to $ShopPage.

If my understanding is right, you could refer to the following code.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['formGoBack'])){
    unlink($outlineimageloc); 
    unlink($imageaftersmooth);
    unlink($jpegorigimageloc); 
    unlink($OrigImageSavename);
    $ShopPage="XXXX";  //set the url here
    header("Location:$ShopPage");   
}
?>
<form id="formGoBack" action="" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="formGoBack" class="btn btn-primary" >Go Back </button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your post - the only problem I'm finding with this solution is that this is causing for the page to rerun through all of the other php script I have on this page, which is taking a lot of time. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: If the page re-runs, you may check the action of the form. If the action is `''` (or same as the page itselft), then the post will be sent to this page again which will cause the re-run.